# ObjectValidator on a List<MyType>

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise-library

I'm using the Enterprise Library validation block to add validation to my inbound data objects within a suite of WCF services.

I have the `[ObjectValidator]` attribute added to my message contracts as below:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyRequest
{
    public MyRequest()
    {
        Header = new MyHeader();
        Data = new List<MyType>();
    }

    [ObjectValidator]
    [MessageHeader]
    public MyHeader Header { get; set; }

    [ObjectValidator]
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public List<MyType> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and my `[DataContract]` for the body is given as this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    [Required, DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [RegularExpressionAttribute(RegexValidation.Name)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [RegularExpressionAttribute(RegexValidation.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }    
}
```

What I notice is that if my `MessageContract` is setup as a `List<MyType>` then the validation doesn't fire. If I remove the `List<>` and use a straight `MyType`, then it does fire.

Its clear that the Enterprise Library code is not going down below the list, and is instead looking for validation items in the `List` object itself. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer really. When using the `ObjectValidator` on a list, you need to use the `ObjectCollectionValidator` instead.